# Is there any way to get the Sense HAT to work with the Raspberry Pi B?

Tags: gpio, pi-b, sense-hat

I purchased a Sense HAT for my Raspberry Pi B (Rev. 2 I think), only to find that the Sense HAT has 40 GPIO pins while my Pi has 26. I have also found that the [Adafruit product page](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2738) says it is not compatible, and was unaware of this when ordering the HAT.

**Is there any way to get it to work** (e.g. with an adapter) or will I need to purchase a newer Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I *think* I'm right in saying that the Sense HAT only uses I2C in which case, theoretically (given the B rev2's I2C pins are in the same place as on the later models), it could use the Sense HAT with an appropriate header in between. However, the HAT identity pins (GPIO 0 and 1) *won't* be connected (because there's not on the P1 header on the B rev2). Whether that matters or not, though, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem but not because I wanted access to some of the GPIO pins. You can find the pins used by the Sense Hat [here](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/sense_hat). Although I am not completely sure I think the Sense Hat only needs one GND pin (please correct me if I am wrong someone). Also, try watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHMwcdIjQeg) tutorial by Kieth's Pi Tutorials.

To clarify (as people have disliked my post!!!), the Sense Hat uses pin 1, pin 2, pin 5 and all the GND pins or 1 GND pin (I don't know which). This means that, using a few jumper wires you could use the Sense Hat with your Raspberry Pi. My only concern is, that the Raspberry Pi Sense Hat software might not work with this set up.

Overall, it is probably best getting a new Pi and the cheapest fix is to get a Pi Zero but of course as you have not got the latest Pi I would recommend upgrading to the Raspberry Pi 3.

Hope this helps,
Louis

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end I just purchased a Raspberry Pi 3. I considered getting a Pi Zero but couldn't find anywhere stating it was officially supported and also would have needed to solder on header myself.